# Generate JWT Token without username and password

Tags: plugins

I am working on generating a JWT token for the users who log in to my site using a plugin [JWT Auth](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-auth/) and that token will be used for a external dashboard.

The issue that I am facing is that for generating a JWT token you need to pass `username` and `password` as `form-data` to `/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token` endpoint but the password that is stored in the database is hashed and cannot be decrypted so what is the solution for this? I cannot send plain text password to the endpoint.

Looking forward to your suggestions.

Comment: I believe the idea is that you're supposed to send it from the user's input, not from the database directly. If you're trying to authenticate an app as a particular user without user input then JWT probably isn't what you want.

Comment: @JacobPeattie ... getting the password of the user directly from the input isn't a good idea and it exposes the users passwords. I have to use the JWT token because the other dashboard requires it.

Comment: How do you think login forms work?

Comment: As long as you POST to a https connection (and password is part of post body), the password should not leak from the request.

Comment: Are you trying to generate a JWT token for a current logged-in user session on your site? You can probably just instantiate the JWTAuth\Auth class and call generate_token with the current user object. Or add a new endpoint, or modify the existing endpoint, to use the current logged-in user from session cookies and not require username and password if the user is logged in.

Comment: @Rup ... You are right ... I will create a new endpoint and have the user's ID as the object for the payload

Comment: Come to think of it removing the plugin from the equation and creating a custom funtionality would be far better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the developers who are facing the similar issue here is what I have done to achieve the desired results.

The best way would be to develop the functionality from scratch but due to a tight deadline I opted to modify the [JWT Auth Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-auth/)

I have modified the method `get_token` in the file `class-auth.php`. What I have done is that at first the method was looking for params `username` and `password` and I have modified it to receive `userID` as the param required. Why `userID` ? It is because I am running a `cURL` call to get the user data after the user sign in. Here is the code for the `get_token` method if anyone wants to use it. Although it was a small modification but it produces the required results. Thank you all for the suggestions. Happy Coding

```
public function get_token(WP_REST_Request $request)
    {
        $secret_key = defined('JWT_AUTH_SECRET_KEY') ? JWT_AUTH_SECRET_KEY : false;

        $userID = $request->get_param('user_id');
        $custom_auth = $request->get_param('custom_auth');

        // First thing, check the secret key if not exist return a error.
        if (!$secret_key) {
            return new WP_REST_Response(
                array(
                    'success' => false,
                    'statusCode' => 403,
                    'code' => 'jwt_auth_bad_config',
                    'message' => __('JWT is not configurated properly.', 'jwt-auth'),
                    'data' => array(),
                )
            );
        }

        // Getting data for the logged in user.
        $user = get_user_by('id', $userID);

        // If the authentication is failed return error response.
        if (!$user) {
            // $error_code = $user->get_error_code();

            return new WP_REST_Response(
                array(
                    'success' => false,
                    'statusCode' => 403,
                    'code' => 404,
                    'message' => 'User does not exists.',
                    'data' => array(),
                )
            );
        }

        return $this->generate_token($user, false);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use custom_auth parameter to handle this kind of situations

---

**Edited**

The JWT has a filter called jwt_auth_custom_auth, it will run when it receives a payload that contain 'custom_auth' you need to hook to that filter using add_fitler function see the code below.

In my case the first block of code goes to my rest api custom endpoint
where i used it to login/register users using only email address

The second block is to hook to the filter and i chose to put it in my plugin file, but you can put it also in you theme's function.php file

You can see the logic in this file wp-content\plugins\jwt-auth\class-auth.php lines 115 -> 160

---

```php
$_request = new WP_REST_Request( 'POST', '/jwt-auth/v1/token' );
$_request->set_header( 'content-type', 'application/json' );
$_request->set_body(
    json_encode(
        [
            'username'    => $email,
            'custom_auth' => true,
        ]
    )
);
$response = rest_do_request( $_request );
return $response->data['data']['token']; // this will return a token
```

And in your function.php

```php
add_filter(
    'jwt_auth_do_custom_auth',
    function ( $custom_auth_error, $username, $password, $custom_auth ) {
        if ( is_wp_error( $custom_auth_error ) ) {
            return null;
        }
        $user = get_user_by( 'email', $username );
        return $user;
    },10,4);
```

I hope this helps

NOTE: not tested

Comment: Can you elaborate on your code to make things a little more clear - where does the first block go? It looks like it should be in a function (the `return` statement), does that function hook in somewhere?

Comment: I have updated my answer, I hope it helps